# ROR : what does validate option do in belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, belongs-to

I'm new to ROR. Can anyone tell me what does the `validate` option do in `belongs_to` with an example?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, validate => true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rare cases Rails allows to create an parent object for the dependent, for example:
`product.create_category!` ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)). About `validate` option docs:

> :validate If false, don’t validate the associated objects when saving
>   the parent object. false by default.

That means that when you save the product, by default the category is not validated. In your case the category will be validated.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to):

> If false, don’t validate the associated objects when saving the parent object. false by default.

So when it's true, it will validate the category when saving the product.